# jhipster import jdl error when importing JDL

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I'm new in Jhipster. After install it last version 7 got this error when try to import JDL: ERROR! Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/context'
Try downgradring to version 6, but same error.

Any advice?

Thanks

**Complete stack error:**

ERROR! Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/context'
Require stack:

- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/limit.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/index.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/statistics.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/app/prompts.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/app/index.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/environment-builder.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js
- /Users/rafa/desarrollo/personal/jhipster/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js

Answer (score 0):

try  this on project directory

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and then

```
npm install
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, but same result, same error.

Comment: Downgrade again but this time to the version 5.8.2, and work ok. Maybe a issue y new versions?  I keep searching... thanks

Comment: I noticed that we have two different jhipster versions: ones global and other internally in the project.  I removed both, reinstall it the 6.1.2 and works ok. But the error persist in latest version 7.0. I will continue working with 6.1.2. Thanks!